# Solar Array Theory Misunderstanding

Tags: solar-cell, theory

I am new to solar panels and I understand their is a lot more physics involved but I am trying to understand this basic concept. Wherever I look it is told that PV panels add Their voltage in series and add their current in parallel. While this is pretty intuitive, I am curious how a current can flow between the panels when the output of each module is a fixed voltage (Assuming each panel in parallel is the same).Since the voltage across the harnesses are equal, would there not be no current flowing?

Again I am new to Solar and am sure that I am missing something, I am just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Let me avoid a direct answer (there's more to learn and a direct answer wouldn't really help, yet) and just suggest that you look at the curve for a single solar cell. If there's no current drawn, the voltage will be a maximum (that varies though with instantaneous insolation.) If the maximum current is drawn (short circuit) then the voltage is zero. Either way, the usable power is zero. Somewhere in the middle there is a place where you take just the right amount of current such that the `V*I` is at a peak value. This is called the MPP. And tracking it is called MPPT.

Comment: Short answer Va != Vb unless R= 0 since V of each panel depends on load and you're giving them unequal loads.

Answer (score 0):

Solar panels aren't really constant voltage sources.  The rating plate or data sheet will quote a nominal voltage and a nominal maximum current under ideal sunny conditions.

But in practice the voltage you get depends on how sunny it is and how much current you try to draw from the panel.

If you increase the current draw from zero amps, the voltage drops slowly until you hit the "maximum power point" for that panel with that amount of sunlight.  Increase the current any further, and the voltage will collapse to nearly zero.

So if you wire panels in parallel, then the leads may have slightly different resistances.  But as soon as you connect a load to them, the voltages will drop until it all balances out.